# How to restore my HDD after try Ubuntu LiveUSB?

Tags: usb, uninstall, live-usb

I'm about to try Ubuntu 13.04 x64 by booting from my external HDD (500 GB).

After trying I might want to restore the HDD back to normal. Is it possible?

I have backup the MBR as Universal USB Creator said it would overwrite the existing MBR with Syslinux MBR.

Comment: You can 'Try Ubuntu' from a Live CD, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD#How-To_LiveCD_Ubuntu

Comment: You would just need to format the drive and create a new partition table.

Answer (score 1):

After you get a LiveUSB or LiveCD you will need to boot from it. To change the boot you **don't need to modify your HDD**.

And after you boot from it, if you only *Try it*, your HDD wont be modified neither.

Remember that you can try Ubuntu from [the Ubuntu Web Site](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/take-the-tour) using nothing more than your web browser!

---

**Conclusion**: after try Ubuntu you wont need to restore your HDD because it will not (should) be modified on the process..